# HOC: A valid React element (or null) must be returned

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create HOC to wrap modals in, and am getting this error: `A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

I have checked the few other threads, and the issues mainly seem to be imports - however I do not believe that is the case here. Here is my code:

create-modal.js

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import Layout from '../../components/layouts/main'
import ModalContainer from './modal-container'

// Modal Layouts
import Empty from './empty'
import Basic from './basic'

const data = {
  title: 'Silly Modal.',
  layout: 'empty',
  customClass: '',
  multiStep: false,
  steps: [
    {
      isVisible: true,
      isAnimated: false,
      animationName: null,
      header: 'TEST',
      currentContent: 'Testing the modal. What fun!',
      buttons: {
        closeText: 'Close',
        closeAction: null,
        continueText: null,
        continueAction: null,
      },
      closeRedirect: null,
      closeRedirectPath: null,
      continueRedirect: null,
      continueRedirectPath: null,
    },
  ],
}

function newModal (WrappedComponent, data) {
  if (!WrappedComponent && !data) return null

  return class Modal extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props)
    }
    render () {
      return (
        <Layout>
          <ModalContainer>
            <WrappedComponent />
          </ModalContainer>
        </Layout>
      )
    }
  }
}

console.log('what is newModal returning?!', (newModal(<Basic />, data)) )

export default newModal
```

console.logging the return of calling this HOC shows that it is returning a function rather than a component:

`function Modal(props) {
      (0, _classCallCheck3.default)(this, Modal);
      return (0, _possibleConstructorReturn3.default)(this, (Modal.__proto__ || (0, _getPrototypeOf2.default)(Modal)).call(this, props…`

Which seems wrong.

I should also note that I may be doing this return wrong (but am not sure. I have tried `return <WrappedComponent />` with the same result however :(

All of the components I am importing are exported as `default` so not using the brackets on the import is, I believe, correct here. I am new to HOC's and am just not seeing what is wrong, as I am following the patterns I see for them closely. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you forget to export a component somewhere.

Comment: @SanjitSingh I am not sure, but i have gone over the imports and exports a bunch of times, however sometimes you just need fresh eyes.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the class constructor with this statement:

```
return class Modal extends Component {
```

which is why it's complaining

You could probably just use a pure React component, as you appear not to be needing props or state.

That will get you past this problem, but I suspect you need to do it differently anyway, because it looks like you want to pass in an element, and render that element inside a modal wrapper.

Look up how to use {this.props.children} for a clue, or if I'm on the right track I can help you more.

**UPDATE**

I think what you want to do is take advantage of children. You can do something like this:

```
<ModalWrapper name="A modal dialog (which is generic and re-usable)">
  <SomethingElse name="This is my custom component">
     :
     :
  </SomethingElse>
</ModalWrapper>
```

In the render method of ModalWrapper you just render `{this.props.children}` and it brings in whatever markup you have as children.

(I am not 100% sure if it's {this.props.children}, but you'll get my drift

Comment: I am following the pattern I see here in the react docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html ...with that said, I agree, I am returning a class constructor - which seems counter-intuitive to me at this point, but I figured I'd get used to it. The code I posted is just the most basic version of this, I will need it to do a lot more, and will need `state`and `props` as I develop it...but right now I am just tying to get it to render in it's most basic form as a HOC

Comment: you are correct in what I am trying to do however, there are different modals, with different layouts - that i want passed through this wrapper because they will have similar functionality that i do not want to duplicate

Comment: I think that just using children is a possible option, however I wanted to be able to call the modal and pass in custom components, as each modal's body and layout may differ. I guess I can do the same thing by importing each component to the modal container and using a switch. It seems like a good situation for a HOC (a concept and pattern which I have been wanting to play with and learn) but for the sake of getting it done, I may just use the `children` approach. Thanks so much for your input :)

Comment: I understand where you are trying to go with this, but the problem is that you can't know ahead of time what components go in, so the children approach means that you don't need to know, you just say where the children go (and they can have their own children too). It's a different approach, something like the React way

Answer (score 0):

An HOC is a function that receives a Component, wraps it to add more functionality and return another component. It is not that you can use it as a Component in your code. You use it to enhance an existing Component.

Comment: You can use it as a component in your code. For example a common pattern is to use connect to create a "container" component. connect is an HOC

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the HOC component correctly, you should do it like this:

```
import Basic from './basic'
...
const NewModal = newModal(Basic, data)
...
render()
<NewModal ... />
```

Look at the official react documentation for an example:
https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html